# Deploy a Python project on a server with no compiler and no internet connection

Tags: python, deployment, pip

There's a Python project I want to deploy on a production server which has no internet connection and no compiler. The project is using *SQLAlchemy* and *pip install sqlalchemy* requires a compiler to work.

The server is running a Debian stable version. Because Debian is what it is, packages are mainly outdated and using the system package manager is not an option.

I can create a local pip mirror and a build server with the same configuration than the production one (with a compiler). Note that I want to run the code from a *virtualenv*.
A Python *virtualenv* inserts absolute paths in files located in *virtualenv/bin/* so if I wanted to create the *virtualenv* on the build server and copy it to the production server, I'd need to modify those files to update paths accordingly (which I try to avoid, even if making the modification is not really a big deal).

How should I package my application ? How the deployment is supposed to work, step by step ?

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I would be extremely tempted to just build a chroot environment that includes everything you need.  Then just tar up the chroot, and drop it in a folder on the server, and add a startup script that runs the chroot.

Comment: This questions is really useful to a lot of people, and you may find your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13754897/565999

Answer (score 1):

If virtualenv is the tool you want, you could check using the --relocatable option, though it may not work unless the two machines are mostly identical, possibly down to the dot version of Python:

```
virtualenv --relocatable ENV
```